# Alias field generated from subquery inside select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select query like this:

```
SELECT 
emp_des_company as 'Company', 
(SELECT pav_des_valor FROM slt_pergunta_avaliacao pa, slt_avaliacao a WHERE pa.pav_idn_pergunta = 393 AND c.cas_idn_avaliacao = a.avl_idn_avaliacao)
FROM slt.case
...
```

How can i alias this subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
emp_des_company as 'Company', 
(SELECT pav_des_valor FROM slt_pergunta_avaliacao pa, slt_avaliacao a WHERE pa.pav_idn_pergunta = 393 AND c.cas_idn_avaliacao = a.avl_idn_avaliacao) as (SELECT per_des_descricao WHERE per_idn_pergunta = 393) 
FROM slt.case
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible using static sql.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? "SELECT per_des_descricao WHERE per_idn_pergunta = 393" does not have FROM clause.

Comment: Hi RubioRic, i just forgot the from clause. What i want is a dinamic alias for a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply use dynamic values for column aliases in static SQL.
You will have to use a fixed value instead: `AS column_name`

One alternative that would make it possible is to create your query dynamically, look into [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is not possible. Thanks for the tip!